# why wont the elif in my while loop work?

Tags: python

i just started learning python and tried making a basic while loop, but when i run it,it doesnt run the elif statement i.e. if the userguess is == "tiger" it doesnt print "almost"..
as im new to this any explanation would be appreciated. thanks

```
animal = "lion"
userguess = raw_input("guess an animal: ")

while userguess != animal:
  userguess = raw_input("guess an animal: ")
  if userguess == animal:
    print("you got it")
    break
  elif userguess == "tiger":
    print("almost, try again: ")
  else:
    print("try again: ")
```

Comment: What *does* it do instead…?

Comment: Does the code work as expected with "lion"?

Comment: Are you aware that you are asking for input twice at the beginning?

Comment: @PM haha, I always forget some of Python's short comings, like it's lack of a true for loop and a do-while loop. I'll delete that comment. Thank you!

Comment: @TurnipEntropy You may see them as shortcomings, Guido probably doesn't. "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it". ;) FWIW, even though I used C for decades before coming to Python I quite like Python's `for` loop. I admit that I do occasionally miss `do...while`, but I can put up with that for the sake of the "one obvious way" philosophy.

Answer (score 5):

It's because you're calling `raw_input` *twice* before you reach the `if` block. So the user will have to enter two animals before any checking occurs.

```
guess an animal: tiger
guess an animal: tiger
almost, try again:
guess an animal:
```

If you want the user to only have to guess once, move the second `raw_input` to the end of the loop.

```
animal = "lion"
userguess = raw_input("guess an animal: ")

while userguess != animal:
  if userguess == animal:
    print("you got it")
    break
  elif userguess == "tiger":
    print("almost, try again: ")
  else:
    print("try again: ")
  userguess = raw_input("guess an animal: ")
```

Alternatively, leave the second `raw_input` call where it is, and replace the first call with a dummy value.

```
animal = "lion"
userguess = None

while userguess != animal:
  userguess = raw_input("guess an animal: ")
  if userguess == animal:
    print("you got it")
    break
  elif userguess == "tiger":
    print("almost, try again: ")
  else:
    print("try again: ")
```

You could also remove the initial assignment entirely, along with the while loop's conditional. As is, The condition is never triggering anyway because you always `break` before reaching the end of the block when `animal` is "lion".

```
animal = "lion"

while True:
  userguess = raw_input("guess an animal: ")
  if userguess == animal:
    print("you got it")
    break
  elif userguess == "tiger":
    print("almost, try again: ")
  else:
    print("try again: ")
```

The second and third ways may be preferable to the first, because they ensure that "you got it" will be printed even when the user guesses "lion" on their first try.

Comment: great reply, thanks for taking the time to write it!